# Auto-indenting copied text

Tags: cut-copy-paste, indentation

I would like to auto-indent text blocks that I have just `put`. At a minimum, I would like to `retab` the new block of text, since otherwise I sometimes end up with tabs in files that shouldn't have tabs when I copy them from files that *do* have tabs without noticing.

Comment: This does not directly answer your question but regarding visibility of tabs, I use this `:set listchars=tab:\|\ ,trail:_,extends:>,precedes:<,nbsp:% list`

Comment: @cychoi I have an autocmd on buffer-load that checks for tabs and uses something like that to turn them bright yellow if they *are* present, but otherwise I don't want to see leading spaces so I only include trailing spaces in `listchars`. I suppose I could include tabs as well, though....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my current solution, but I'm certianly open to better ones:

```
nnoremap p pV`]=
nnoremap P PV`]=
```

This makes use of the `]` built-in mark, which is the "last character of the previously changed or yanked text" (from `:help marks`).

I'd prefer not to remap primitive fundamental keys such as `p`, and this won't work with other methods of pasting (e.g. the middle-click in X11). Also, I haven't used this for very long so I'm not sure yet if there are any behavioral oddities.

Comment: You could also do `[p` or `]p`.

Comment: @romainl I didn't know about that, but that does indeed seem to do what I want.

Comment: @romainl Actually, that appears to remove leading spaces when pasting below a blank line, which is not necessarily what I want.

Comment: Which is why there are both a `[p` (which is probably better written as `]P`) and a `]p`

Comment: `[p` and `]p` are to be used when you want to paste while keeping the indent of the line above or below. They are not magical replacements for `P` and `p`.

Comment: @romainl ....so why did you suggest them, then? Autoindent correctly ignores blank lines; it wouldn't have been surprising if `[p` did the same.